# lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that every subset of $S$ is measurable, Then measure of $S$ equal to

Tags: measure-theory

$S$ be a non empty lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that every subset of $S$ is  measurable, Then measure of $S$ equal to

$1.$ measure of any bounded subset of $S$.

$2.$ measure of any closed subset of $S$

$3.$ measure of any  subset of $S$

$4.$  measure of any countable subset of $S$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the construction of the vitali set?

Just assume that $\mu(S)\neq 0$ and use the vitali set construction on $S$.

So you see the only subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with this proberty are null sets.

A rough sketch for the vitali set:

Define on $[0,1]$ an equivalence relation via $$x\sim y \iff x-y\in \mathbb{Q}$$
Let $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in I}$ be a complete representative system of $[0,1]$, meaning 
you have exactly one representative of every equivalence class.

Now we define the set
$$N:=\bigcup_{\alpha \in I} \{x_\alpha\}$$

Furthermore we know that $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is countable so we take an 
enumeration $(v_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. In addition we define
$$N_n:= N+v_n =\{ x\in\mathbb{R}: x=y+v_n \text{ with } y\in N\}$$
and see that 
$$\mu(N_n)=\mu(N)$$
as the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.

From the construction we see that 
$$ [0,1]\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} N_n \subseteq [-1,2],$$
hence 
$$1 \leq \mu\Big( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty N_n\Big)\leq 3.$$
On the other hand the $N_n$ are pairwise disjoint meaning $N_n \cap N_m=\varnothing$ when
$n\neq m$.

From the $\sigma$-additivity we know that 
$$\mu\Big( \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty N_n\Big)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(N_n)$$
and as $\mu(N_n)=\mu(N)$ we sum over a constant.

Now there are 2 cases: $\mu(N)=0$, then the sum will be $0$ and not greater than $1$.

When $\mu(N)>0$, then the sum will be $\infty$ and not lower than $3$, hence $N$ can't be measurable

Comment: I don't know the construction of vitali set

Comment: Do you know any non measurable set?

Comment: Do you know the theorem of Caratheodory that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with positive measure has a non-measurable subset?

Comment: No sir, I don't know that too

Comment: @AndréNicolas are there proofs of the Caratheodory theorem not using the Vitali set construction

Comment: Sorry, I do not know, it has been a while.

Comment: @SenoreBunuel give me some minutes I give you the idea

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Thank you

Comment: @SenoreBunuel added the construction, you just need to apply it to your set (at first make your set bounded)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis: Even after making the set bounded and applying Vitali construction to obtain $\cup N+r_i=K, $say, how can one show that K is inside S?